# Bash should I use ; in if statement and is there any difference?

Tags: bash, if-statement

can someone, please, explain is there any difference in two following examples?

1. First example

   if [ command ]**;** then
   ...
   fi
2. Second example

   if [ command ] then
   ...
   fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example does not work unless you put `then` into a new line. Using the semicolon allows you to put `then` into the same line as `if`. People argue which is more readable, it's just a matter of taste, no technical difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, sschuberth!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with an answer be sure to also accept it, not only upvote it ;-)

Comment: Yes, of course :) It asked me to wait n minutes, before I can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

The second is an error. There *must* be a command separator between the command passed to `if` and the `then` clause. The command separator does not *have* to be a semicolon (a newline is sufficient), but there must be one.